# What is the difference between these two DERIVED-SUB Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three tables of `characters`, `elements` and `characters_elemenets` applying these two queries http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee104a/7

what i wanna do is to bring a specific character and its powers sorted by its manifestation percentage using this relation to get the results of

```
character   elemental_control
Alpha       Fire,Wind,Earth
Beta        Wind,Earth
Coco        (null)
Delta       Earth,Water,Fire,Wind
```

but by **one specific** `character_id` as the query in link

but i do not understand what is the difference between both these queries in the long run and its performance except that one is **subquery** and the other is **derived**

Comment: Is the question about terminology?  Or about performance?  Are these the real tables, or are they fabricated for the Question?  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table for how to speed up `characters_elemenets`.

Comment: @RickJames about the performance of my queries and the difference in how they function to affect that performance despite giving same results - they are real tables in a project i have